# I have created a very simple Tic Tak Toe game, I am having trouble with the indexing and win checking with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked here already and dont fully understand it. I have been stuck on this for an entire month and have tried asking elsewhere but with no luck.

The code that I wrote is awful to say the least but it is code i understand. It would be greatly appreciated if anyone can help me in a way that a simpleton like me can understand it.

```js
function clearButton (){
    $('td').text('')        // Clears button
}

var turn = 1;                       // sets turn

$('td').on('click', function(){
    var tableRow = $(this).closest('tr').index()        // index of row
    var tableColumn = $(this).closest('td').index()     // index of column

    if (turn === 1){
        $(this).text('O')
    }else if (turn === -1){                         // turns
        $(this).text('X')
    }else{
        console.log('oops');
    }

    $('td').on('dblclick', function(){
        $(this).text('')                            // double click to clear td
    })

    $('button').on('click', clearButton)                // call to clear button 

    console.log(tableRow, tableColumn)                 // logs row and column

    for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        console.log(table[i]);                              // work on this
    }

    turn = turn * -1                                   // changes turn
})
```

```css
table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }

td {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   background-color: rgb(238, 227, 130);
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 70px;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
 
body {
    background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

.jumbotron {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
 }

.jumbotron button {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
        <button class='btn btn-primary' type="submit">CLEAR</button>
</div>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

is there another platform where i can ask questions like this without pissing off a bunch of established developers? I literally have no resource other than to ask questions on here I know have already been answered, i just dont understand them that well yet.

Comment: Can you add some CSS so the table renders in this example?

Comment: Check if you won't find something helpful here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90183/simple-javascript-tic-tac-toe

Comment: @tshimkus Done.

Comment: You might want to add the CSS in the code snippets so we can run it and actually see it

Comment: I just moved it there so the code will be executable once approved

Comment: @MchlanguWilliamSipho I was originally just going to resort to this to check for a win but there must be a more easy and efficient way of doing this...

Comment: @IlllIl done, sorry about that, it should be working now

Answer (score 1):

I've added a couple things to your code, that hopefully will help you get to the next step. The first is that I created an array of 9 elements called table. Then when a player clicks on a square, that table gets populated with either "X" or "O":

```
const table = Array(9);
table[tableRow * 3 + tableColumn] = turn < 0 ? "X" : "0";
```

Next I created a function called `checkForWinner()`. All this function does now is console.log the results of `table`. Hopefully you can take it from there:

```js
function clearButton (){
    $('td').text('')        // Clears button
}

var turn = 1;                       // sets turn

const table = Array(9);

$('td').on('click', function(){
    var tableRow = $(this).closest('tr').index()        // index of row
    var tableColumn = $(this).closest('td').index()     // index of column

    if (turn === 1){
        $(this).text('O')
    }else if (turn === -1){                         // turns
        $(this).text('X')
    }else{
        console.log('oops');
    }

    $('td').on('dblclick', function(){
        $(this).text('')                            // double click to clear td
    })

    $('button').on('click', clearButton)                // call to clear button 

    table[tableRow * 3 + tableColumn] = turn < 0 ? "X" : "0";
    checkForWinner();
    
    turn = turn * -1                                   // changes turn
})

function checkForWinner(){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(table));
}
```

```css
td{
   border:solid 1px #000;
   height:30px;
   width:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
        <button class='btn btn-primary' type="submit">CLEAR</button>
</div>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works really well, I have a question about something though. `table[tableRow * 3 + tableColumn] = turn < 0 ? "X" : "0";` I dont really understand whats going on here. I understand that if the turn is negative that it picks O or else X.... but why `table[tableRow * 3 + tableColumn]`? I'm not really sure what this is doing.... thanks for any clarification, im still trying to get this down.

Comment: also, i am having trouble with the win checker. I have the horizontal done and it works. but I tried to make the vertical checker and it broke everything. `function horizontalWin(){            
   if (table[0] === table[1] && table[2] || table[3] === table[4] && table[5] || table[6] === table[7] && table[8]) {
     console.log('win');
   }
}`  and then vertical: function verticalWin(){            
   if (table[0] === table[3] == table[6] || table[1] === table[4] && table[7] || table[2] === table[5] && table[8]) {
     console.log('win');
   }
}` its the same thing i dont get it...

Comment: `table[tableRow * 3 + tableColumn] = turn < 0 ? "X" : "0";` is a ternary operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator that sets the cell clicked on in the TTT board to "X" or "0"

Comment: @Dylancam909 for your functions, replace the &&s with ===. For example, `table[1] === table[4] === table[7]`

Answer (score 1):

Not the best answer, but my step is to turn the location (col, row) into 1D location, and "hard" check for winner.

```js
var checkedBox = {};
function clearButton(){
  $('td').text('')        // Clears button
  checkedBox = {}
}


function checkWinner() {
  return (checkedBox['0'] && checkedBox['0'] === checkedBox['1'] && checkedBox['1'] === checkedBox['2'])
  || (checkedBox['3'] && checkedBox['3'] === checkedBox['4'] && checkedBox['4'] === checkedBox['5'])
  || (checkedBox['6'] && checkedBox['6'] === checkedBox['7'] && checkedBox['7'] === checkedBox['8'])
  || (checkedBox['0'] && checkedBox['0'] === checkedBox['3'] && checkedBox['3'] === checkedBox['6'])
  || (checkedBox['1'] && checkedBox['1'] === checkedBox['4'] && checkedBox['4'] === checkedBox['7'])
  || (checkedBox['2'] && checkedBox['2'] === checkedBox['5'] && checkedBox['5'] === checkedBox['8'])
  || (checkedBox['0'] && checkedBox['0'] === checkedBox['4'] && checkedBox['4'] === checkedBox['8'])
  || (checkedBox['2'] && checkedBox['2'] === checkedBox['4'] && checkedBox['4'] === checkedBox['6'])
}

var turn = 1;                       // sets turn

$('td').on('click', function(){
  var tableRow = $(this).closest('tr').index()        // index of row
  var tableColumn = $(this).closest('td').index()     // index of column
  if (turn === 1){
      $(this).text('O')
  }else if (turn === -1){                         // turns
      $(this).text('X')
  }else{
      return console.log('oops');
  }

  const boxIndex = tableRow * 3 + tableColumn;
  checkedBox[boxIndex] = turn === 1 ? 'O' : 'X';
  if (checkWinner()) {
    alert(`Winner is ${turn === 1 ? 'O' : 'X'}`);
    return clearButton();
  }

  $('td').on('dblclick', function(){
      $(this).text('')                            // double click to clear td
  })

  $('button').on('click', clearButton)                // call to clear button 
  turn = turn * -1                                   // changes turn
})
```

```css
  table {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
   }

  td {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     border: 1px solid black;
     background-color: rgb(238, 227, 130);
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 70px;
  }

  h1 {
      margin-top: 0px;
      text-align: center;
  }

  body {
      background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  }

  .jumbotron {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      padding-top: 10px;
   }

  .jumbotron button {
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
            <button class='btn btn-primary' type="submit">CLEAR</button>
    </div>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I was going to do something similar if I couldn't find a more efficient way of doing it but this just seems really unnecessary. Thank you for taking the time to help. This is what I'm going to use if i cant figure out something more efficient and i think the first post will be my best bet :)